# Yeoman grunt could not connect to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meanjs

I have been trying to run a Yeoman generated app, but every single time I run the command `grunt`, I run into the same error:

```
PS C:\Users\Aiden\yo\mean> grunt
Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
>> Local Npm module "grunt-node-inspector" not found. Is it installed?

Running "env:dev" (env) task

Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Warning:
You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to 
work.
More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass
 Used --force, continuing.

Running "less:dist" (less) task

Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
>> 87 files lint free.

Running "csslint:all" (csslint) task
>> 2 files lint free.

Running "mkdir:upload" task

Running "copy:localConfig" (copy) task


Running "concurrent:default" (concurrent) task
    Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR
    >> TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR
    >> TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    >> Local Npm module "grunt-node-inspector" not found. Is it installed?
    >> Local Npm module "grunt-node-inspector" not found. Is it installed?

    Running "watch" task
    Waiting...

    Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task
    [nodemon] 1.11.0
    [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
    [nodemon] watching: server.js config/**/*.js modules/*/server/**/*.js
    [nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
(node:8744) DeprecationWarning: node --debug is deprecated. Please use node --inspect instead.
Debugger listening on 127.0.0.1:5858


Could not connect to MongoDB!
{ MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Aiden\yo\mean\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:328:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> 
(C:\Users\Aiden\yo\mean\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-
core\lib\connection\pool.js:274:1
2)
         at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
         at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
         at Connection.emit (events.js:194:7)
         at Socket.<anonymous> 
(C:\Users\Aiden\yo\mean\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb-
core\lib\connection\connection.js:177
:49)
        at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1279:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]' }
     C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe: src\debug-agent.cc:147: Assertion `(err) == (0)' failed.
    [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I have tried every single solution I was able to find regarding this issue, including installing at least a dozen different packages using NPM. I am at a loss. Any ideas?

Comment: At a guess I think you are confusing the installation of installing a package like `mongoose` with the actual install of a MongoDB instance. NPM packages don't install the database, but just the libraries required to access them. See [Install MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/) in the core documentation and select the option appropriate for your platform.

Comment: Hi Neil, thank you for your reply. This was not the case, but I have resolved my problem.