# yeoman generated app crashes on running grunt command

Tags: npm, gruntjs, meanjs, yeoman-generator, yo

I am getting the following error when I run the `grunt` command after generating the app using Yeoman generator:

```
Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
>> Local Npm module "grunt-node-inspector" not found. Is it installed?

Running "env:dev" (env) task

Running "sass:dist" (sass) task

Running "less:dist" (less) task

Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
>> 86 files lint free.

Running "csslint:all" (csslint) task
>> 2 files lint free.

Running "mkdir:upload" task

Running "copy:localConfig" (copy) task
Copied 1 file

Running "concurrent:default" (concurrent) task
Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
>> Local Npm module "grunt-node-inspector" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-node-inspector" not found. Is it installed?

Running "nodemon:dev" (nodemon) task

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: server.js config/**/*.js                 
modules/*/server/**/*.js
[nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
(node:16253) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. Please use `node --inspect` or `node --inspect-brk` instead.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I found a similar question([Yeoman grunt could not connect to MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146570/yeoman-grunt-could-not-connect-to-mongodb)) but I was not able to find the solution to my problem there.

Answer (score 0):

Is that an old version of MEAN.js? I believe `grunt` was replaced by `gulp` and also an issue regarding `node-inspector` was fixed by this [pull request](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/pull/1744).

You should check which version you're using and make the necessary changes.